# Multiple Taxonomy Dynamic Search

Tags: php, wordpress

I've on my wordpress site search from that include multiple (three) taxonomy. Searching is working very well but i'm looking for the issue to hide empty categories

> Taxonomy 1: Brand
>
> Taxonomy 2: Model
>
> Taxonomy 3: Version

I'm looking for possible that after choose "Brand" in model dropdown list will be only category that posts include choosen "Brand".

And similat. In **"Version" Dropdown list will be only categories witch include "Brand" and "Model"**.

Brand

- VW
- Audi

Model

- Golf
- A4

Version

- 1.9TDI
- 2.0 TSFI

Now all dropdowns list are including full list of taxonomy, I want to filter with similar/post with same taxonomy.

Like

1. First Dropdown Lilt - Choose Audi
2. Search posts which taxonomy "Audi" and return all categories from taxonomy "model" to second dropdown
3. Sedond Dropdown list - Choose A3
4. Search posts which taxonomy "A3" and return all categories from taxonomy "model" to third dropdown
5. Run search

```html
<?php
global $theme_search_fields;
if( !empty($theme_search_fields) ):
?>
<div class="as-form-wrap">
    <form class="advance-search-form clearfix" action="<?php global $theme_search_url; echo $theme_search_url; ?>" method="get">

   
        <div class="option-bar large">
            <label for="select-location"><?php _e('Marka', 'framework'); ?></label>
            <span class="selectwrap">
                <select name="location" id="select-location" class="search-select">
                    <?php advance_search_options('property-city'); ?>
                </select>
            </span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="option-bar large">
            <label for="select-status"><?php _e('Model', 'framework'); ?></label>
            <span class="selectwrap">
                <select name="status" id="select-status" class="search-select">
                    <?php advance_search_options('property-status'); ?>
                </select>
            </span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="option-bar large">
            <label for="select-property-type"><?php _e('Wersja', 'framework'); ?></label>
            <span class="selectwrap">
                <select name="type" id="select-property-type" class="search-select">
                    <?php advance_search_options('property-type'); ?>
                </select>
            </span>
        </div>
    


    <div class="option-bar">
        <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Wyszukaj', 'framework'); ?>" class=" real-btn btn">
    </div>

  

    </form>
</div>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tax query for search result as mentioned below, you can customize according to your code . I hope it can help you with using hide empty category.

```
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ),
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'actor',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                ),
            ),
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And for showing hide empty categories please try this :

```
     $categories = get_terms( 'category', array(
        'orderby'    => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
     ) );
```

I hope its help you other than you can revert me. Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: It's similar but no issue, mabye I've describe the problem a little bit more at first post

Comment: Hi Marcin, Okay  means you want to filter taxonomy via their terms  ? What I am getting ,    If you enter "Audi " then all terms listed with this taxonomy like A3, A4 and all .I really appreciate your explanation but i need a little bit more .  Please tell the exact your code i will send you the exact possible answer . Hope that helps you .